# bokeh how to make a column data source column use the second Y-axes for display

Tags: plot, bokeh

I am using a `VBar` glyph to display a bar chart in Bokeh and the data is streamed to it via a `ColumnDataSource`. Additionally, I want to add a different y-axes when plotting thee data from onee of the columns.

So the code is as follows:

```
self.bar_text = ["V1, "V2", "V3"]
self.plot = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*self.bar_text), y_range=[0, 150])
# Now I add an extra y-axes which is displayed correctly
self.plot.extra_y_ranges = {"delay": Range1d(start=0, end=25)}
self.plot.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="delay"), 'right')

# The data will be fed to the graph via th column data source
self.input_sources = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[], top=[], color=[]))
self.bar_glyph = VBar(x="x", top="top", bottom=0, width=0.2, fill_color="color")
self.plot.add_glyph(self.input_sources, self.bar_glyph)
```

I can feed data to this with something like:

```
obj.input_sources.stream(dict(x=['V1', 'V2', "V3"],
                                 top=[30, 50, 10],
                                 color=["blue", "blue", "red"]), 3)
```

However, I am not sure how I can associate the last column `V3` to the second additional y-axes.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. The answer is to use separate data sources and glyphs for them and assign them to the correct `y_range`

```
self.left_input_sources = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[], top=[], color=[]))
self.right_input_sources = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[], top=[], color=[]))
self.left_bar_glyph = VBar(x="x", top="top", bottom=0, width=0.2, fill_color="color")
self.right_bar_glyph = VBar(x="x", top="top", bottom=0, width=0.2, fill_color="color")
self.plot.add_glyph(self.left_input_sources, self.left_bar_glyph)  # Use default y-axes
self.plot.add_glyph(self.right_input_sources, self.right_bar_glyph, y_range_name='delay')
```